# SSIS distributed Transactions Error "Failed to Acquire Connection

Tags: t-sql, transactions, ssis

I am using SSIS built-in transactions. Scenario is as following

There are two databases on Same Server and I need to Merge them (INSERT/UPDATE)
I am using SQL Merge Clause to do so. There are few Master Tables and each one has Couple of Child tables. Merge Statements Runs on Master Table first and then I have ExecuteSQL tasks for Child tables. Child Tables ExecuteSQL runs in Parallel.

While doing this i am getting Failed to acquire connection and task fails on one of the parallel running ExecuteSQL tasks. Could not figure out what is the cause.

RetainSameConnection is set to false and if i set it to True it gives "Transaction Context is in use by another session" Error.

As i understand i don't need RetainSameConnection = True as It's only required in Local TSQL based transactions. DTC is enabled and working.

NOT all tasks fails in my package and that suggests it succuessfully acquired the connection by somehow fails on Parallel tasks.

Comment: If i run all child merge statements in Sequence it works

Comment: No one is willing to give it a try

Comment: Use a `sql profiler` and check which  query is causing an issue . I think due to table lock your child tasks in parallel is having issues in acquiring the connections

Comment: SQL profiler does not show anything. Looks like Quer does not go to SQL Server when it fails

Answer (score 0):

The "Failed to acquire connection" message is almost always due to the fact that you have a task that validates the connection before it is setup properly.

In most SSIS projects, your connections are bound to local databases for development purposes. Then, you have either expressions, variables, script tasks or something like that that sets the real connection at runtime.

When a package is starting it's execution, every component that has the "DelayValidation" attribute set to "False" (the default value!) will try to connect to the datasource before any tasks are executed, which means that it will try to connect to the database you have set in your development environment before updating it's properties...